# After cloning a repository using ssh keys, What is the meaning of Permanently added 'gitlab.com' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts

Tags: git, ssh, ssh-keys

After I have cloned an empty repository to my local system, I just want to clarify each of these 3 lines what is their meaning.

```
Warning: Permanently added 'gitlab.com' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.
client_global_hostkeys_private_confirm: server gave bad signature for RSA key 0
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
```

I am just a curious person

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bssh%5D+Permanently+added+to+the+list+of+known+hosts

Answer (score 1):

That is an SSH thing.  It asked you if the remote's key is OK the first time it saw it, and then remembers that.